# Efficiency of for loop iteration on a python generator

Tags: python, performance, generator

I was going through generator in python and I got understood the advantage of generators.

Consider the example

```
mygenerator = (x*x for x in range(3))
```

case A:

```
for i in mygenerator:   
    print i
```

Say in the above example, instead of for loop, I used

case B:

```
next(mygenerator)
```

Are case A and case B the same in terms of complexity?

I mean if I am using a `for` loop like  in case A, will I get benefit of generator? Or do I always have to use `next()` for better benefits?

Comment: `next()` makes **one** step at a time. You'd have to compare the `for` with `while True` loop. It's slower, because you ultimately access the same results but with separate `next()` global lookups and calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `next()` is *not an equivalent*. `next()` produces the next value in the iterator, it is not a drop-in replacement for `for` using a loop.

You'd have to use a `while True` loop:

```
while True:
    try:
        i = next(mygenerator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

This is *slower*, because this involves repeated `next` name resolutions. It is otherwise not more efficient.

`for` uses `iter()` on the generator (which will return `self`), and then internally calls the same method `next()` would call, the `__next__()` method on the iterator.

Ultimately, you can test if something is more efficient (performant), with the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html):

```
 >>> from timeit import timeit
>>> while_loop = '''\
... while True:
...     try:
...         i = next(g)
...     except StopIteration:
...         break
...
... '''
>>> timeit('for i in g: pass', 'g = (x*x for x in range(1000000))')
0.15362663206178695
>>> timeit(while_loop, 'g = (x*x for x in range(1000000))')
0.568918940029107
```

So for a generator producing 1 million items, the `for` loop is almost 4 times faster.

The advantages of generator functions and generator expressions are *memory efficiency*, and in many cases, code clarity. `for` and `next()` are two very different use-cases to get values from your generators, use what you need for the problem at hand.

Comment: yeah, yeah! I am aware of the fact. What i was trying to confirm  was if i use while(True)  and use next() inside while as you said AND the case A i mentioned in question are same in internal implementation?

Comment: @syam: `for` uses `iter()` on the object, then calls the moral equivalent of `next()` on that. But all this happens in C code, so is far more efficient.